# Sql lite to text file

Tags: android

I would like to ask if it is possible to export my sql lite database into text file? If yes, how? Thank you..

I want to export to.txt, so I can convert it without using a 3rd party software for conversion.

Comment: Sure-  read every row of every table and write it as text, probably using  CSV library (CSV is a better format for something like this than plain text).  Of course you're going to have to fine or write this functionality.

Comment: @GabeSechan do you sell a source code? I'm looking for a mobile bluetooth printing using android phone and import/export sqlite database.